# I am using wicket 1.4 and want to select multiple files at a time using multipleFileUploadfiled

Tags: java, wicket

I am using wicket 1.4 and want to select multiple files at a time using MultiFileUploadField to upload files. is it possible to do that in given scenario? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is what this component is designed for.

Comment: i read that to upload multiple files in wicket we neet 1.5 and or above version...

Comment: It is available in 1.4.x: https://github.com/apache/wicket/tree/wicket-1.4.x/wicket/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/upload